# IIS URL Rewrite for Domains That Share Website

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have two domains both pointing to the same IIS website

```
domain1.com/website1

domain2.com/website1
```

I would like to write a URL Rewrite rule to point

```
domain1.com/*
```

to a specific subdomain

```
domain2.com/subfolder.
```

I can't figure out the IIS URL rewrite rule to accomplish this. Below is what I have:

```
<rule name="redirect" enabled="true" >stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1\.com*$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://domain2.com/subfolder" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
<rule name="redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1\.com*$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://domain2.com/subfolder" />
</rule>
```

i think there is a typo in your code, there is a ">" before stopProcessing that shouldnt be there.